# Angular 2 directives error

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I'm using the final Angular 2 release version. I have set up the startup file as mentioned in official site [angular 2 quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). In my **app.component.ts** file I've made 2 components. The code is shown below:-

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    template:`
        <h2>Hi, demo !!</h2>
    `
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){

    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1> 
    <demo></demo>
    `

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){

    }
}
```

In the component of **my-app** I've used directives selector which is an array. But the editor(VS Code) is showing error. The console of chrome is throwing an error, telling that 
**Template parse errors:
'demo' is not a known element:**
[image: Chrome console]

please help me fix this. Thanks

Here's my **app.module.ts** file

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, DemoComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define your component in the `declarations` property of your module.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppComponent, DemoComponent  }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DemoComponent ], <== here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And remove it from `directives` property of `AppComponent`. It is deprecated.

**app.component.ts**

```
 directives: [DemoComponent] ,
```

Comment: Whatever you have said I have done that. But it still showing the error. :(

Comment: You forgot to import `DemoComponent`

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. It Worked :)

Answer (score 2):

`directives` is deprecated. Create an `NgModule` and add it to the `declarations` instead.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: I'm new to angular 2. So can you please elaborate.

Comment: follow @yurzui's example for a quick fix but also read the documentation I posted in full when you get the chance. I can't elaborate better than the documentation can.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare **DemoComponent** in declaration array and make sure you remove `declaration:[DemoComponent]` from **AppComponent**

***FYI*** : declaring pipes,component, directives in directives metadata of @Component({}) decorator have been removed. that declaration is not longer there. So you're facing some issues. You need to declare pipes,directives,components in @NgModule({}) decorator.

if there are in the same file you need to import it as `import { AppComponent,DemoComponent}   from './app.component';`

```
import {DemoComponent} from 'valid path';             //<<===here
OR   
import {AppComponent, DemoComponent} from './app.component';  //<<===here


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,DemoComponent],       //<<<====here
  providers:[],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: if there are in the same file you need to import it as `import { ppComponent,DemoComponent}   from './app.component';`